# Is the use of the tense correct?

Tags: grammar, tenses

I am not sure about the tenses in the following sentences. Is it the right choice?

1) I am originally from XYZ, studied XYZ in XYZ and will stay in XYZ until the end of March 2020.

( maybe 'have studied' or 'having studied' ? )

2) The last year I have been working in a XYZ company being responsible for XYZ in the northeasterly part of Poland.

(I am not working there anymore, so probably it has to be: 'I worked' ?)

Comment: Hi @alex, welcome to Stack Exchange! Proofreading is not a service offered by this website. Here at Stack Exchange, questions must be on-topic and specific in nature. For example, "How did the word 'often' acquire its peculiar spelling?" or, "Is this sentence's use of the past participle correct and why?"

Your question appears to be requesting proofreading help and would be closed in its current state. If there is something specific in the letter that confuses you or that you don't understand, please edit the question to ask about that specific thing. Thanks!

Comment: I am so sorry. I changed it, is it okay?

Comment: That's better. Some people might appreciate more focus, but this is a good start. If anyone wants more information to answer your question, they can ask for it here. Thanks for editing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second sentence, "have been working" is in the following tense:

> Present Perfect Progressive: Present perfect progressive tense
>   describes an action that began in the past, continues in the present,
>   and may continue into the future. This tense is formed by using
>   has/have been and the present participle of the verb (the verb form
>   ending in -ing).

Since the action no longer "continues in the present"--it "was started and finished in the past"--the past tense "worked" (as you suggested) would be a correct alternative to the incorrect present perfect progressive tense ("have been working"). For more on verb tenses, click on the link below to view the reference cited.

https://leo.stcloudstate.edu/grammar/tenses.html

In your 1st sentence, either "studied" (past tense) or "have studied" (present perfect tense--"describes an action that happened at an indefinite time in the past or that began in the past and continues in the present") would be a correct choice (if the action--study--happened as indicated above).

OTOH, "having studied" is a perfect participle (having + past participle), so it is incorrect to use it as part of the compound predicate in your sentence. For more on that and its proper use, click on the following link:

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/es/intermediate-grammar/participle-clauses

Also, see the comment section for other suggested edits to your sentence(s) that are unrelated to your specific questions regarding verb tense.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I am..., (I) studied…, (I) will stay...

The sentence is long, but all the tenses are correct.

> 2) I have been working in a XYZ company being
>   responsible for XYZ in the northeasterly part of Poland.
>
> (I am not working there anymore, so probably it has to be: 'I worked'
>   ?)

Your instinct seems correct. It depends on how long ago, and whether you have since worked at another job.